# How to handle multiple SPA application in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application, I want to serve two Angular apps, one for admin and one for users.

In production, I don't use angular CLI tools so there is only some static files of two angular web applications.

Admin files are in `/angular/admin` and user files are in `/angular/user`.
So, how can I serve them?

I tried multiple calls to `IServiceCollection.AddSpaStaticFiles` but they override each other. [From source repository I found this is Singleton services]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to branch the application middleware pipeline into two and register the SPAs after setting up MVC

````
 ...
 app.UseMvc(...)

 app.Map("/admin",
   adminApp =>
   {
     adminApp.UseSpa(spa =>
     {
       spa.Options.SourcePath = "angular/admin";
       spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
       {
           FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "angular", "admin"))
       };

       if (env.IsDevelopment())
         spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
      });
    });

  app.Map("/user",
    userApp =>
    {
      userApp.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "angular/user";
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "angular", "user"))
        };

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
          spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4201");
      });
  });  

                ```
````

Comment: i wrote what you say but still got **The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' ...** error, until i used `app.Map` to seperate `IApplicationBuilder` to two `appUser` and `appAdmin` then using `appUser.UseSpa(spa => spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = staticFileOptionsUser);` and `appAdmin.UseSpa(spa => spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = staticFileOptionsAdmin);`. thanks for response.

Comment: Yeah that's what I normally do, but I wanted to give you this solution and see if it worked.  xD You have to split the pipeline anyway right? Or do you use angular cli outside of asp net core during development?

Comment: Then it doesn't work without `UseSpa` :). Yes i should split that.

Comment: Also quick tip on doing that, I use `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` instead of `UseAngularCliServer` and start angular cli manually, otherwise angular cli will restart every time you make a change to c# code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaproxyingextensions.useproxytospadevelopmentserver?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: yea that's exactly what i do in development environment

Comment: can you please edit your answer and write the solution you normally do?, so i can mark that as accepted? thanks

Comment: done. Also, you can set up multiple projects inside one angular cli workspace. This way you can share common components and styles between the two projects. https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#setting-up-for-a-multi-project-workspace

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add `spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port: 4200);` (and one entry for port 4201)

Answer (score 1):

another tip: I'm using react and the react-router cannot handle path in URL correctly. So I use a different port for different spa. Use "app.MapWhen(o => o.Request.Host == 6000, ...)" to handle this case.

In production, should be something like : MapWhen(o => o.Request.Host.Host == "a.com"...

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to serve up an Outlook Addin from within my dotnet React based application. This is how I was able to get it to work for both development and production.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
        ...
    }
    

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      ...          

      
        
        app.Map("/addin",
           addin =>
           {
               var sfo = new StaticFileOptions()
               {
                   OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                   {
                       var resp = ctx.Context.Response;
                       resp.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
                       resp.Headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = "0";
                       resp.Headers[HeaderNames.Pragma] = "no-cache";
                   }
               };
               if (!env.IsDevelopment())
               {
                   var dir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "OutlookAddinApp/dist");
                   sfo.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(dir);
               }
               addin.UseSpaStaticFiles(sfo);
               addin.UseSpa(spa =>
               {
                   spa.Options.SourcePath = "OutlookAddinApp";
                   spa.Options.DefaultPage = "/taskpane.html";
                   spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = sfo;

                   if (env.IsDevelopment())
                   {
                       spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                       spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:3000");
                   }
               });
           })
           .Map("",
            root =>
            {
                var sfo = new StaticFileOptions()
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                    {
                        var resp = ctx.Context.Response;
                        resp.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
                        resp.Headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = "0";
                        resp.Headers[HeaderNames.Pragma] = "no-cache";
                    }
                };
                if (!env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    var dir = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp/build");
                    sfo.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(dir);
                }
                root.UseSpaStaticFiles(sfo);
                root.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = sfo;

                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                    }
                });
            });
  }
```