# Get site URL in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to register SPA files based on URLs...I have registered AddHttpContextAccessor but not sure how i can check the url there?

```
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            if (GetUrl(_httpContextAccessor).EndsWith("support") || GetUrl(_httpContextAccessor).EndsWith("support/"))
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            else
                configuration.RootPath = "support-app/build";
        });
```

Comment: You can't get the request pipeline in ConfigureServices, as the pipeline isn't even ready there. Try to put the site URL in your appsettings, read it from there. Or try  to read URL in Configure method in startup class with help of middleware .

Comment: Hi Qing Guo, do you any sample how i can do that? My basic requirement is to set RootPath based on the URL

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to change the root path based on the request url?

Is the reason for this requirement that you are you serving multiple SPA's? If that is the case, you might want to check out this thread that describes how to configure the pipeline to serve multiple apps at different paths:

[How to handle multiple SPA application in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482398/how-to-handle-multiple-spa-application-in-asp-net-core)

If you only have one SPA, then you might need to describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve.